# Living Revocable Trust and Death

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates, income-tax

If a person dies with a living revocable trust then that trust becomes irrevocable at the date of death. When it becomes irrevocable, does the date the trust was created change?

That is, if a person is filing for an EIN number, with the IRS, for the trust and the website asks for the date of trust creation, should he use the original date of creation or the date of death?